# how to skip grub dual boot option menu entirely (without picking an OS to boot)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I'd like to skip the entire Grub 2 interface, where I have to decide booting Linux or Windows

im running linux ubuntu lastest version (14.04.1 LTS) and windows 8.1 both 64 bit versions.

I've installed easyBCD software, which I want to use as (my only) boot manager.

> Issue:
>
> whenever I run my computer, I get grub interface to pick Linux or Windows, after that I get >easyBCD interface where I have to pick linux or windows again. If both choices are the same, proper system boots, else I get thrown back to beggining (grub UI).
>
> I'd like to somehow delete / skip grub from appearing.

TLDR title :) thank you for helping!

Comment: U cannot entirely skip I think. We can reduce the "timeout" to zero. Ensure that grub points to easyBCD partition by default. By doing this, U do not have to do a selection.... and you would feel as though you are directly going to easyBCD

Comment: Is it possible that I can reduce it to 1 second and it works, but when I reduce it to 0 it the timeout goes to default (10)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` and set the followiing

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=[entry you want]
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

then use `update-grub2` command to update your grub configuration. This does not remove the grub but you wont see it anymore and also no interaction is needed. But this also means you have no access to the recovery entries or kernel arguments set by grub. (Though I think Ubuntu has this "hold down shift to force OS selection"-thing but I am not sure of that)

Comment: Yes, but If i choose windows 8.1 to boot in 0 seconds by grub, then I have to do same selection in easyBCD screen, or it kicks me back to beggining

Comment: So you want to do a chainload (going from grub to a other bootlaoder)? For this you need to figure outh where the easyBCD bootloader is located. Then you have to add a custom entry to grub and set it as default as mentioned above. If you give me the details on the easyBCD I migth be able to figure out the propre code that goes into `/etc/grub.d/40_costum`. Just out of cuouriossity, why do you need this easyBCD thing in the first place?